# How to show that $\frac{-1}{x^2}=0$ has no solutions?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I must check if the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ has a tangent line with slope $0$. I took the derivative:

$$\left[\frac{1}{x}\right]'=\frac{-1}{x^2}$$

And then:

$$\frac{-1}{x^2}=0$$

$$\frac{-1\cdot x^{-2}}{-1}=\frac{0}{-1}$$

$$\frac{1}{x^2}=0$$

I guess that the only possible algebraic manipulation to find it would be to multiply both sides by $x^2$ having:

$$\frac{1}{x^2} (x^2)=0(x^2)$$

Which would yield the problematic conclusion:

$$1=0$$

Does this facts alone prove that there are no solutions? I know that it's possible to argue that the graph of $1/x$ has no *visible* line tangent to the $x$-axis. But I'm looking for something on this spirit.

$$$$

Comment: $Something \Rightarrow 1 = 0$ necessarily means that $Something$ is false. So yes, you're done.

Comment: This is a contradiction proof, note first that $x\not=0$.  Therefore, if $-\frac{1}{x^2}=0$ were true, then $1=0$ would also be true, but that's not possible.  Therefore, the original assumption must be wrong.

Comment: Good. But multiplying both sides by $x^2$ is the only possible operation to *solve* that, isn't it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather than argue by contradiction, just note that $x^2>0$ for all $x\not=0$.  And therefore $\frac{-1}{x^2}<0$ for all $x\not=0$.  Therefore the derivative is always negative.

Comment: and x==0 is not in the domain